# Match multiple conditions and avoid records that do not match

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, pivot-table, worksheet-function

Source Data: `SHEET 1` having three columns: `ID`, `STATUS` (Fail/Pass) and `DATE`.

Output should appear on Sheet 2 with records (only `ID` column) which are having Status as "Pass" and Date>today()-7, avoiding records that do not match.

Notes:

```
1. I want to run it for all the records in SHEET 1  
   (number is dynamic, so want to run it on entire column for both Status and Date).  
2. Do not want to have any blank or false value  
   i.e. records that do not match should not show up at all on sheet 2.  
3. Avoid macros.
```

Answer (score 1):

You might, amongst very many other possibilities:

1. Label a column, say D, in SHEET 1, say with `df`, and insert in it and copy down a formula such as:

   ```
   =IF(C2>TODAY()-7,1,0)
   ```

then pivot sheet 1 A:D into Sheet 2 with STATUS and df for FILTERS and ID for ROWS, then select Pass for the STATUS filter and `1` for the df filter.

or

1. Add and copy down a formula in Sheet 2 such as:

   ```
   =IF(AND('SHEET 1'!B2="P",'SHEET 1'!C2>TODAY()-7),'SHEET 1'!A2,"")
   ```

and apply Advanced filter to it with Copy to another location and Unique records only checked.